# Estimating the Transfer function coefficients from input and output data

Tags: matlab, controls

[Input and Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRaj8.jpg)

I want to identify the coefficients of the TF. I have the input and output response. I can build a tf and verify the results, but I was thinking of a better way to identify the system using MATLAB. My approach was as follows:

```
Ts=0.1; 
input=[0 1 1 1 1 1 1]';
output=[0 1.5 1.45 1.4050 1.3645 1.3281 1.2952]';
% data=iddata(y, u, Ts)
% sys=tfest(data,2,1);

% create iddata object by specifying output signal, input signal, and sampling time
data=iddata(output,input,0.1);
% estimate a transfer function with 2 poles and 1 zero
sys=tfest(data,2,1);

But I don't manage to get the correct coefficients. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: what are the correct coefficients?

Comment: have you tried a sample time lower than 0.1 and passing more samples?

Comment: The transfer function is in the form of b0+b1z^-1/1+a1z^-1 , the values of bo=1.5 , b1=-1.4 and a1=-0.90. This is the discrete-time representation. I have a fixed number of samples of my data. The image attached to the question, is all the data I have.

Comment: @ignacio Thankyou for the support. The problem stands resolved. I had to make small tweaks to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use anything but pen&paper for this task.

You can resolve the TF `D(z) = Y(z)/U(z)`, which (indicating time samples by `k`) gives in discrete-time domain:

```
y(k) = -a1 * y(k-1) + b0 * u(k) + b1 * u(k-1)
```

You have three unknowns - `a1`, `b0` and `b1` - which you can easily find by filling in three of your seven given IO-pairs and solving the resulting set of three equations.

Obviously, you can formulate this as a linear system `Ax = b` with `x = [a1, b0, b1]`, filling the rows of `A` and `b` accordingly. Then you could make use of Matlab's pseudo inverse `x = A\b` to find the coefficients, in case the coefficients have to be found by a least-squares fit.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The least-squares fit cannot provide a solution to a varying input signal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "varying input signal"? You can run the least-squares fit even online (i.e., in each sample you record) in a batch-fashion - the input won't get much more varying than this, right?